# How to use mapStateToProps inside another action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

As I'm new to redux can someone help me if it is possible to make a change in one action based on the state change from different another file.

actions.js

```
export function setChangeNotification(changeNotification: boolean) {
return {
    type: SET_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION,
    changeNotification
};
}
```

Toolbar.js

```
endMeetingForAll () {
    const { _changeNotification } = this.props;
    this.props.dispatch(setChangeNotification(true)); //changed value set to true but at default it's false in my initial state.
    console.log(_changeNotification,'changeNotification from end meeting'); //Checked if value changed using mapStateToProps. 
}
function _mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
    _changeNotification: Boolean(state['features/toolbox'].changeNotification)
};
}
export default translate(connect(_mapStateToProps)(Toolbox));
```

Another action.js where I need to make a change

```
export function notifyKickedOut(participant: Object, _: ?Function) { // eslint-disable-line 
no-unused-vars
return (dispatch: Dispatch<any>, getState: Function) => {
    const args = {
        participantDisplayName:
            getParticipantDisplayName(getState, participant.getId())
    };
    dispatch(showNotification({
        appearance: NOTIFICATION_TYPE.ERROR,
        hideErrorSupportLink: true,
        descriptionKey: 'dialog.kickMessage',
        descriptionArguments: args,
        titleKey: 'dialog.kickTitle',
        titleArguments: args
    }));
    //JAAM CODE
    // when the paticipant removed after redirect to the website.
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            window.APP.conference.hangup(false);
            executeCommand('hangup');
            window.close();
        },
        NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT);
};
}
```

In the above action.js I need to dispatch another shownotification if setChangeNotification is true like

```
  if(changeNotification){
    dispatch(showNotification({
        appearance: NOTIFICATION_TYPE.ERROR,
        descriptionKey: 'dialog.changed',
        titleKey: 'dialog.changed'
    })); 
   }else{
   dispatch(showNotification({
        appearance: NOTIFICATION_TYPE.ERROR,
        hideErrorSupportLink: true,
        descriptionKey: 'dialog.kickMessage',
        descriptionArguments: args,
        titleKey: 'dialog.kickTitle',
        titleArguments: args
    }));
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the state via calling `getState()`. Since this looks like a thunk (async action creator) you can dispatch any action you'd like there.

Comment: I have some small problem over here. My state isn't updating even after dispatch. It stays false always like on it's initial state.

Comment: @shanks_9790 We would need to see your reducer to debug this I guess, hard to say what's going wrong.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfl6npthzr3r1op/reducer.txt?dl=0 Can you look into this reducer?

Comment: @shanks_9790 Yes, it looks ok. Could be something else in your setup. Probably better to fix a simple state change before making the thunk work.

Comment: Is there some other way to update it to the store?

Comment: You could dispatch another action right in the react component. Right after `this.props.dispatch(setChangeNotification(true));` you know that the state has just changed for sure. Getting the hang of the thunk middleware is an important learning step for react-redux apps though :)